# Check if a string exists in an array even as a substring in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to work out if a string exists in an array, even if it's a substring of a value in the array.

I've tried a few methods and just can't get it to work, not sure where I'm going wrong.

I have the below code, you can see that $val2 exists within $val1, but I always get a FALSE when I run it.

```
$val1 = "folder1\folder2\folder3"
$val2 = "folder1\folder2"
$val3 = "folder9"

$val_array = @()

$val_array += $val1
$val_array += $val3

$null -ne ($val_array | ? { $val2 -match $_ })  # Returns $true
```

I also tried:

```
foreach ($item in $val_array) {
if ($item -match $val2) {
Write-Host "yes"
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69132749/45375) offers the best solution to your problem**, using [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) matching via the [`-like`  operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like).

Note:

- The need to *escape* select characters in a search pattern in order for the pattern to be taken *verbatim* in principle also applies to the wildcard-based `-like` operator, not just to the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match), but since wildcard expressions have far fewer [metacharacters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) than regexes - namely just `*`, `?`, and `[` - the need for such escaping doesn't often arise in practice; whereas regexes require `\` as the escape characters, wildcards use `` ` ``, and *programmatic* escaping can be achieved with [`[WildcardPattern]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern.Escape)
- Unfortunately, **as of PowerShell 7.2, there is *no* dedicated operator for *verbatim* substring matching**:

  - A **workaround** for this limitation is to call **the `[string]` .NET type's [`.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Contains) method** (on a *single* input string only), however, this performs **case-*sensitive* matching**, whereas PowerShell operators are case-*insensitive* by default, but offer case-sensitive variants simply by prefixing the operator name with `c` (e.g., `-clike`, `-cmatch`).
  - In *Windows PowerShell*, `.Contains()` is *invariably* case-sensitive, but **in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* an additional overload is available that offers case-*insensitive* matching**:

    ```sh
     'Foo'.Contains('fo') # -> $false, due to case difference

     # PowerShell (Core) 7+ *only*:
     'Foo'.Contains('fo', 'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase') # -> $true
    ```
  - *Caveat*: Despite the name similarity, PowerShell's [`-contains` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) does *not* perform substring matching; instead, it tests whether a collection contains a given element (in full).

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Your primary problem is that **you've accidentally swapped the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match)'s operands**: the search pattern - which is invariably **interpreted as a *regex*** ([regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)) - must be on the ***RHS***.
- As iRon points out, **in order for your search pattern to be taken *verbatim* (literally), you need to *escape regex metacharacters with* `\`**, and the robust, **programmatic way to do this is with [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape)**.

Therefore, the *immediate* fix would have been (`?` is a built-in alias of the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet):

```sh
# OK, but SLOW.
$val_array | ? { $_ -match [regex]::Escape($val2) }
```

However, this solution is *inefficient* (it involves the pipeline and a cmdlet).

Fortunately, **PowerShell's comparison operators can be applied to arrays (collections) *directly*, in which case they act as *filters***, i.e. they return the *sub-array of matching elements* - see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#common-features).

iRon's answer uses this technique with `-like`, but it equally works with `-match`, so that your expression can be simplified to the following, much more efficient form:

```sh
# MUCH FASTER.
$val_array -match [regex]::Escape($val2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`-Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#matching-operators) operator does a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) comparison. Where the backslash character (`\`) has a special meaning (it escapes the following character).

Instead you might use the `-Like` operator:

```
$val_array -Like "*$val2*"
```

Yields:

```
folder1\folder2\folder3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the string method `Contains`:

```
$null -ne ($val_array | ? { $_.Contains($val2) })
```

Comment: Note that `bool Contains(string value)` is case sensitive.